# Mirror a specific path to another url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use two separate url's, pointing to two separate websites, using one hosting and one backend.

So far there's only one website (I'll name it domain1.com).
And there's already some mod-rewriting used.

1. redirecting www.domain1.com to domain1.com

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.domain1.com$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
2. using nice urls, so domain1.com/news/item points to domain1.com/index.php?/news/item

   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

What I would like to achieve are the following things

1. domain1.com/specific_folder_name/123456789 should point to domain2.com/123456789 just for cosmetics
2. domain2.com/123456789 should run /index.php?/specific_folder_name/123456789

It should result in this:

when surfing to domain1.com/param1/param2, the server gives you index.php?/param1/param2
whan surfing to domain1.com/specific_folder_name/123456789 you get redirected to domain2.com/123456789 and the server gives you /index.php?/specific_folder_name/123456789

I hope this is clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get this done via **ProxyPass Directive**

> This directive allows remote servers to be mapped into the space of
>   the local server; the local server does not act as a proxy in the
>   conventional sense, but appears to be a mirror of the remote server.
>   The local server is often called a reverse proxy or gateway. The path
>   is the name of a local virtual path; url is a partial URL for the
>   remote server and cannot include a query string.

[more details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)